# How to correctly handle and show concurrency exceptions thrown from DB Layer to MVC View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have the following problem

I have a grid which is bound to a collection of Zones, but zone have States, In this Gridview I want to delete Zones, but in the api controller I check if there are stes related to it, if there is at least one, I should print an error message.  However the problem is

1. First I delete a zone which have states then the error is shown on the div
2. I delete a zone which has no states, it shows the same message again even if its success, I debugged this and in the API controller, the code never goes to the CreateErrorResponse line, it goes to the CreateReponse with Status OK, however in the view, the error handler is fired and I still get the DB Update Concurrency Error that the zone cant be deleted because it has states, but the record is deleted anyways.

This is my api method

```
// DELETE api/Zona/5
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteZona(int id)
        {
            Zona zona = unitOfWork.ZonaRepository.GetByID(id);

            if (zona == null) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); }

            if(!zona.Departamentos.Any())
            unitOfWork.ZonaRepository.Delete(zona.ZonaID);
            else return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "No se puede eliminar el registro, tiene elementos relacionados");
            try
            {
                unitOfWork.Save();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, zona);
        }
```

And this is my view with the error handler

```
@model List<xx.Comisiones.Models.Ciudad>
@using xx.Comisiones.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ciudad";
}

<h2>Ciudades</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Ciudad>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CiudadID).Title("ID");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Nombre).Title("Nombre");
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Departamento, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ListDepartamentos"], "DepartamentoID", "Nombre")
        .Title("Departamento");
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit().Text("Editar")
                .UpdateText("Guardar")
                .CancelText("Cancelar");
            command.Destroy().Text("Eliminar");
        }).Title("Acciones");
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Nuevo"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true))
        .Events(events => events.Edit("insertPopupCaption"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .AutoBind(true)
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .WebApi()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.CiudadID);
            model.Field(p => p.CiudadID).Editable(false);
        })
            .Create(create => create.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Ciudad" }))) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
            .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Ciudad" }))) // Action invoked when the grid needs data
            .Update(update => update.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Ciudad", id = "{0}" })))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Ciudad", id = "{0}" }))) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
    )
)
<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e != null && e.status == "error" && e.errorThrown != "Not Found") {
            var message = JSON.parse(e.xhr.responseText);
            ShowMessage(e.xhr.statusText, message.Message);
            $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        }
    }

    function insertPopupCaption(e) {
        if (e.model.isNew()) {
            $('.k-window-title').text("Nuevo");
        } else $('.k-window-title').text("Editar");
    }
</script>
```

And I have a JS script with the function that shows the message.

```
function ShowMessage(alertType, stringMessage) {
    if (alertType == "warning") {
        document.getElementById("alert_warning").style.display = "block";
        $("#alert_warning").text(stringMessage);
        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("alert_warning").style.display = "none"; }, 4000);

        document.getElementById("alert_danger").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_success").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_info").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (alertType == "Conflict") {
        document.getElementById("alert_danger").style.display = "block";
        $("#alert_danger").text(stringMessage);
        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("alert_danger").style.display = "none"; }, 4000);

        document.getElementById("alert_warning").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_success").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_info").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (alertType == "info") {
        document.getElementById("alert_info").style.display = "block";
        $("#alert_info").text(stringMessage);
        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("alert_info").style.display = "none"; }, 4000);

        document.getElementById("alert_warning").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_success").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_danger").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (alertType == "OK") {
        document.getElementById("alert_success").style.display = "block";
        $("#alert_success").text(stringMessage);
        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("alert_success").style.display = "none"; }, 4000);

        document.getElementById("alert_warning").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_info").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert_danger").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and btw, I have these divs on my layouts file

```
<div style="display:none" id="alert_info" class="alert alert-info" role="alert"></div>
<div style="display:none" id="alert_warning" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"></div>
<div style="display:none" id="alert_danger" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
```

Comment: maybe you have something else that fires the error_handler?  what browser are you using? IE has some cache issues with ajax

Comment: he is using firefox and chrome